# practical r-value references

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, move-semantics

I thought I might try my hand at move semantics.  So I caught a very [grainy/lowres video of Scott Meyers talking about move semantics](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/move-semanticsperfect-forwarding-and-rvalue-references), although the code in said video was unreadable.

So I've written a throw away class that wraps a vector of string.

```
class ShoppingList
{
private:
    vector<string> m_vsList;
public:
    ...
};
```

I was wondering if it was possible to use move semantics to move a temporary vector of string into the member variable m_vsList?

To accomplish this, I might write a move function like:

```
void MoveList( vector<string> && r )
{
    m_vsList = std::move(r);
}
```

I should state that I'm trying this on VS2011 beta compiler.

**Questions**

Is this correct / possible?  If so, how can I specify a temporary `vector<string>`?

e.g. `MoveList( {string("c"), string("b"), string("a")} )` is invalid.

Should I restrict move semantics to move constructors and/or move assignment overloads?

If I std::move into m_vsList and m_vsList already contains data, what happens to that data, does it leak?  So should I explicitly clear that vector before the move?

Comment: Try `MoveList(std::vector<std::string>{"c", "b", "a"});`.

Comment: Or, if your compiler doesn't have initializer lists yet: `MoveList(std::move(my_vector_of_strings));`

Comment: KerrekSB: MoveList(vector<string>{"x", "y"}); doesn't work.

Comment: compiler is VS 2011 beta

Comment: @freefallr : VC11 doesn't support uniform initialization.

Comment: ildjarn: uniform initialization?

Comment: The syntax @KerrekSB demonstrated.

Comment: Instead of using std::move on the vector you might consider using swap.  Why?  The vector probably has an = operator that does the same thing, but it's more explicit this way.  You know exactly what you want to do when you're fed an rvalue like that, I'd think about just doing it rather than hide what you want behind a fairly generic interface.  Use the generic interface when you don't know what needs to be done because you're writing a template or something.

Comment: Seems reasonable.  I hadn't considered that.  I'll give it a go, thanks

Comment: While, as was said, it is possible it's probably not the most useful thing: why not just create a function `void set_vsList(std::vector<string> r){m_vsList=std::move(r);}`, then you can still decide at the call side whether the argument should be copied or moved.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: SetList / GetList move functions I've considered both.  They both seem extremely useful optimizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's correct and possible.  See the rvalue-enabled version of `std::map::operator[] (Key&& key)`.

If you want to create a temporary for testing, what you have listed above should work once your compiler fully supports initializer lists.  For now, you could create a function that returns a `std::vector<std::string>` or simply create a non-temporary vector and use `std::move`

Comment: Does anyone know if VS2011 will _ever_ support initializer lists ?

Comment: VS2011 won't, but VS2012 might. MS said they plan to implement the full standard some day.

Comment: I thought that moving non-temporary (l-value) variables was a bad thing unless you're absolutely certain that it'll never be used again.  Even at that, it seems like bad practise.

Comment: @freefallr What do you _want_ to move from in the first place? There's no way to initialize an unnamed vector with meaningful data without copying or support for C++11 initialization.

Comment: @ComicSansMS : Sure there is -- return it from a function.

Comment: I didn't know that VS2011 didn't support c++11 initialization.  I had no specific problem to solve, I'm just prototyping to learn about move semantics.

Answer (score 0):

If you compiler does not support initialiser list, you can make empty rvalue vector  with:

```
MoveList(vector<string>());
```

Or non empty rvalue:

```
vector<string>  lv_vec; 
lv_vec = ...
MoveList(vector<string>(lv_vec));
```